# Removing item in localstorage is not working, token issue

Tags: javascript, laravel, api

Can someone help me, I think removing item is not working in this code.

I experience this error "The resource owner or authorization server denied the request."
I have an issue in token. Can someone help me.
Thank you very much

```
export const logout = {
  data() {
    return {
      token: localStorage.token
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logout() {
      let config = {
        url: '/api/logout',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
        },
      };
      axios(config)
        .then(response => {
          localStorage.removeItem('token');
          localStorage.removeItem('user_role');
          localStorage.removeItem('redirect_to');
          this.$router.push({
            path: '/login'
          });
          console.log(response.statusText);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
  }
};
```

This is my code in my controller, can someone help me to solve this or explain to what is the error and where it come from. thank you

```
public function logout() {
  $token = Auth::user()->token();
  $token->revoke();
  return response(['message' => 'You have been successfully logged out.'], 201);
}
```

Comment: To me this problem seems unrelated to `localStorage` and more related to your server denying the request, but perhaps I am missing something...

Comment: Do you think this is connected to the revoking the token?

Comment: @Unwellee can you share where did you see this error ? Was in the chrome console ? if so, share the full error please, if it was in Javascript. share the exact line of code that is reporting this error.

Comment: it comes from the console log in my project. and this is the exact line of the error. The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. at \\vendor\\league\\oauth2-server\\src\\Exception\\OAuthServerException.php:243)

Comment: Look in the devtools-- I suspect you'll see your call to the logout endpoint returning with an error, and (if it is configured correctly) a non-2xx level status code.